# To take maximum qty and price on listview in nextpage

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I am adding `sr`,`Item`,`Quantity` and `Price` after clicking on the show button in a ListView on the next page. I am able to add all data on the next page but the problem is that I only want to show `sr`,`Item`,`maximum Quantity` and `Maximum price` in the ListView on the next page.

Here is my code :

**Mainactivity.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button show;
    ListView list_item;
    private ArrayList<Integer> sr;
    private ArrayList<String> item;
    private ArrayList<Integer> quantity;
    private ArrayList<Integer> price;


    private ArrayList<Integer> sr1;
    private ArrayList<String> item1;
    private ArrayList<Integer> price1;
    private ArrayList<Integer> data1;
    SearchView searchView;
    private ArrayList<String> filterlist;
    public Custom custom;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        list_item = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listdetails);


show=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnview);
        sr = new ArrayList<>();
        item = new ArrayList<>();
        quantity = new ArrayList<>();
        price = new ArrayList<>();

        sr1 = new ArrayList<>();
        item1 = new ArrayList<>();
        data1= new ArrayList<>();
        price1= new ArrayList<>();

        filterlist = new ArrayList<>();
        item = filterlist;


        sr.add(1);
        sr.add(2);
        sr.add(3);
        sr.add(4);

        item.add("Book");
        item.add("pen");
        item.add("pencil");
        item.add("Eraser");


        quantity.add(0);
        quantity.add(0);
        quantity.add(0);
        quantity.add(0);


        price.add(20);
        price.add(30);
        price.add(5);
        price.add(5);


        Custom c = new Custom(this, sr, item, quantity, price, sr1,item1,data1,price1);
        list_item.setAdapter(c);

        show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Trial.class);
                intent.putExtra("sr",sr1);
                intent.putExtra("item",item1);
                intent.putExtra("qty",data1);
                intent.putExtra("price",price1);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

**Custom.java**

```
public class Custom  extends BaseAdapter {

    Activity a;
    public ArrayList<Integer> sr;
    public ArrayList<String> item;
    public ArrayList<Integer> quantity;
    public ArrayList<Integer> price;


    public ArrayList<Integer> sr1;
    public ArrayList<String> item1;
    public ArrayList<Integer> data1;
    public ArrayList<Integer> price1;
    public ArrayList<String> filterlist;


    int bookCount = 0;
    int penCount = 0;
    int pencilCount = 0;
    int eraserCount=0;

    int bookPrice = 0;
    int penPrice = 0;
    int pencilPrice = 0;
    int eraserPrice=0;


    private String data, pricedata;

    public Custom(Activity a, ArrayList<Integer> sr, ArrayList<String> item, ArrayList<Integer> quantity, ArrayList<Integer> price, ArrayList<Integer> sr1, ArrayList<String> item1, ArrayList<Integer> data1, ArrayList<Integer> price1) {
        this.a = a;
        this.sr = sr;
        this.item = item;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.price = price;
        this.sr1 = sr1;
        this.item1 = item1;
        this.data1 = data1;
        this.price1 = price1;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return item.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return item.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }








    public class Holder{
        TextView sr1,item1,qty1,price1;
        Button pl,min;

    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final Holder holder=new Holder();
        LayoutInflater li=a.getLayoutInflater();
        final View view=li.inflate(R.layout.customlist,parent,false);

        holder.sr1=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.s_no);
        holder.item1=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.i_name);
        holder.qty1=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.qty);
        holder.price1=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.pr);
        holder.pl=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.pl);
        holder.min=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.min);


         holder.sr1.setText(String.valueOf(sr.get(position)));

        holder.item1.setText(item.get(position));
         holder.qty1.setText(String.valueOf(quantity.get(position)));
        holder.price1.setText(String.valueOf(price.get(position)));


        holder.pl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        if (bookCount >= 0) {
                            bookCount++;
                            bookPrice = bookPrice + 20;
                            sr.get(position);
                            item.get(position);

                        }
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        if (penCount >= 0) {
                            penCount++;
                            penPrice += 30;

                            sr.get(position);
                            item.get(position);

                        }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        if (pencilCount >= 0) {
                            pencilCount++;
                            pencilPrice += 5;

                            sr.get(position);
                            item.get(position);
                            //holder.qty1.setText(String.valueOf(pencilCount));
                            //holder.price1.setText(String.valueOf(pencilPrice));
                        }
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        if(eraserCount>=0){
                            eraserCount++;
                            eraserPrice +=5;

                            sr.get(position);
                            item.get(position);

                        }
                        break;
                }
              if(position==0)
              {

                  holder.qty1.setText(String.valueOf(bookCount));
                  holder.price1.setText(String.valueOf(bookPrice));

                  sr1.add(sr.get(position));
                  item1.add(item.get(position));
                  data1.add(bookCount);
                  price1.add(bookPrice);

              }
                if(position==1)
              {
                  holder.qty1.setText(String.valueOf(penCount));
                  holder.price1.setText(String.valueOf(penPrice));

                  sr1.add(sr.get(position));
                  item1.add(item.get(position));
                  data1.add(penCount);
                  price1.add(penPrice);

              }
                else if(position==2)
              {
                  holder.qty1.setText(String.valueOf(pencilCount));
                  holder.price1.setText(String.valueOf(pencilPrice));

                  sr1.add(sr.get(position));
                  item1.add(item.get(position));
                  data1.add(pencilCount);
                  price1.add(pencilPrice);
              }
                else if(position==3)
              {
                  holder.qty1.setText(String.valueOf(eraserCount));
                  holder.price1.setText(String.valueOf(eraserPrice));

                  sr1.add(sr.get(position));
                  item1.add(item.get(position));
                  data1.add(eraserCount);
                  price1.add(eraserPrice);

              }


            }
        });





        holder.min.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        if (bookCount > 0) {
                            bookCount--;
                            bookPrice -= 20;

                            sr.get(position);
                            item.get(position);

                        }
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        if (penCount > 0) {
                            penCount--;
                            penPrice -= 30;

                            sr.get(position);
                            item.get(position);

                        }
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        if (pencilCount > 0) {
                            pencilCount--;
                            pencilPrice -= 5;

                            sr.get(position);
                            item.get(position);

                        }
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        if(eraserCount > 0){
                            eraserCount--;
                            eraserPrice-=5;

                            sr.get(position);
                            item.get(position);               
                        }
                        break;
                }

                if(position==0)
                {
                    holder.qty1.setText(String.valueOf(bookCount));
                    holder.price1.setText(String.valueOf(bookPrice));

                    sr1.add(sr.get(position));
                    item1.add(item.get(position));
                    data1.add(bookCount);
                    price1.add(bookPrice);

                }
                else if(position==1)
                {
                    holder.qty1.setText(String.valueOf(penCount));
                    holder.price1.setText(String.valueOf(penPrice));

                    sr1.add(sr.get(position));
                    item1.add(item.get(position));
                    data1.add(penCount);
                    price1.add(penPrice);
                }
                else if(position==2)
                {
                    holder.qty1.setText(String.valueOf(pencilCount));
                    holder.price1.setText(String.valueOf(pencilPrice));

                    sr1.add(sr.get(position));
                    item1.add(item.get(position));
                    data1.add(pencilCount);
                    price1.add(pencilPrice);
                }
                else if(position==3)
                {
                    holder.qty1.setText(String.valueOf(eraserCount));
                    holder.price1.setText(String.valueOf(eraserPrice));

                    sr1.add(sr.get(position));
                    item1.add(item.get(position));
                    data1.add(eraserCount);
                    price1.add(eraserPrice);

                }


            }
        });

        return view;


    }


}
```

**Trial.java**

```
public class Trial extends Activity {
    ListView listnew;


    ArrayList<Integer> sr1;
    ArrayList<String> item1;
    ArrayList<Integer> data;
    ArrayList<Integer> price;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.trial);
        data=new ArrayList<>();
        price=new ArrayList<>();
        listnew=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.newlist);

        Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
        sr1=bundle.getIntegerArrayList("sr");
        item1=bundle.getStringArrayList("item");
        data=bundle.getIntegerArrayList("qty");
        price=bundle.getIntegerArrayList("price");


        Custom_Trial ct=new Custom_Trial(this,sr1,item1,data,price);
        listnew.setAdapter(ct);

    }
}
```

**Custom_Trial.java**

```
public class Custom_Trial extends BaseAdapter {
    Activity a;

    ArrayList<Integer> sr1;
    ArrayList<String> item1;
    ArrayList<Integer> data;
    ArrayList<Integer> price;

    public Custom_Trial(Activity a, ArrayList<Integer> sr1, ArrayList<String> item1, ArrayList<Integer> data, ArrayList<Integer> price) {
        this.a = a;
        this.sr1 = sr1;
        this.item1 = item1;
        this.data = data;
        this.price = price;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    public class Holder{
        TextView sr,it,qty,amt;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Holder holder=new Holder();
        LayoutInflater li=a.getLayoutInflater();
        View view=li.inflate(R.layout.customtrial,parent,false);
        holder.sr=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.head1);
        holder.it=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.head2);
        holder.qty=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.head3);
        holder.amt=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.head4);


        holder.sr.setText(String.valueOf(sr1.get(position)));
        holder.it.setText(item1.get(position));
        holder.qty.setText(String.valueOf(data.get(position)));
        holder.amt.setText(String.valueOf(price.get(position)));


       // holder.amt.setText(data.get(position));


        return view;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.abc.logic.MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/item_name"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sr_no"

        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/srno"
            android:layout_below="@+id/breakfast"
            android:text="ITEM NAME"
            android:id="@+id/itemname"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/qtity"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_name"

        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/itemname"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lunch"
            android:text="QTY"
            android:id="@+id/quantity"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/count"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/qtity"

        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rate"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/count"

        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/quantity"
            android:layout_below="@+id/snacks"
            android:text="PRICE"
            android:id="@+id/price"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/sr_no"
        android:orientation="horizontal"

        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/breakfast"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="SR.NO"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:id="@+id/srno"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:id="@+id/listdetails"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item_name"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">


    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnview"
        android:text="View"
        android:layout_below="@+id/listdetails"
        android:clickable="true">

    </Button>


</RelativeLayout>


customlist.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/s_no"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/i_name"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/s_no"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/pl"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/qty"
        android:background="@drawable/plus1"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/qty"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/i_name"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/min"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/pl"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/qty"
        android:background="@drawable/minus1"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/pr"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/min"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pl"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/pl" />




</RelativeLayout>

custom_trial.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/head1"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/head2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/head1"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/head3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/head2"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/head4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/head3"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
</RelativeLayout>

trial.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/head1"
        android:text="SrNo"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/head2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/head1"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Item"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/head3"
        android:text="Qty"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/head2"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/head4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/head3"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Price"
        />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/newlist"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/head1"

        >


    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's the screenshot output :

[image]

Comment: Here is screenshot of my output https://postimg.cc/image/n2l5i65qf/

Comment: i want to show 1 Book 3 60, 2 pen 4 120 and not all data as it is in screenshot.

Comment: Can anyone give me correct code plz